# Site can't be reached: Server IP address can't be found ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

Tags: google-cloud-platform, wordpress-admin, appengine-wordpress

Please bear with me, I'm a newb. I have a domain through google, hosting through gcp, and using wordpress click to deploy. My site was built and working fine. I did some work on it yesterday to add and update several pages. Everything was good. I followed a tutorial on onepagezen for free SSL certificate setup. Again, everything was fine after and https was working. Then a bit later all of a sudden, I am getting this error, and cannot access my website or my wp-admin dashboard. I've checked my DNS configuration and it's still the correct external ip. I tried resetting my vm instance, but no luck. I would gladly provide some code if I knew what if any would do any good. Halp?

Answer (score 0):

It is related to your onepagezen and WordPress set up. They are not related to the GCP.
You can check your steps by following [this document](https://onepagezen.com/free-ssl-certificate-wordpress-google-cloud-bitnami/) for Free SSL Certificate Setup for WordPress on Google Cloud and [this onepagezen’s document](https://onepagezen.com/domain-name-configuration-wordpress-google-cloud/#wordpress-bitnami-instructions) for Domain Name Configuration for WordPress on Google Cloud. As these are third party documents, Google cannot guarantee the validity of the information they contain.

If you do not need this SSL, you can remove it.